# How to use a remote Jupyter server in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to use a remote Jupyter server via SSH with VSCode but I get an error whenever I try to specify the URI of any server. This also happens with local instances of Jupyter. Any server that is not started by VS Code seems to be unusable.

I am just starting a server like this

```sh
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8080
```

Then I  enter the address in VSCode with the correct port and token
[image: http://localhost:8080/?token=...]

Nothing happens and I get this error, as you can see in the log below.

> **Command 'Python: Specify local or remote Jupyter server for connections' resulted in an error (Running the contributed command: 'python.datascience.selectjupyteruri' failed.)**

[image: VSCode console log]

Has anyone else been experiencing anything similar? I honestly have no idea how to troubleshoot this. It is worth noting that selecting the **Default:** *VS Code will automatically start a server for you on localhost* option raises the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running a fairly old version of the Python extension, as the `python.datascience.selectjupyteruri` command no longer exists in the Python extension—it is now provided in a [standalone Jupyter extension](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/introducing-the-jupyter-extension-for-vs-code/). Please consider upgrading to the latest version of the Python and Jupyter extensions. If that doesn't resolve the problem, please file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues and we'll be happy to help.